# How to compute Integrated Squared Error for kernel density estimation in R

Tags: self-study, kernel-smoothing

I am working on R for kernel density estimation. I am testing different kernels and I need to evaluate them. I use next code for density estimation:

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(250) 
#Computing of bandwidth
h1 <- bw.ucv(x1)
#Estimate
est <- density(x1,kernel = "gaussian",bw = h1)
#Values
est$y
```

I am using the function `density` with gaussian kernel and bandwidth computed from unbiased crossvalidation. The `est$y` values are the estimations from kernel. I have to evaluate these estimations with Integrated Squared Error. This is expressed as $ISE=\int\{\hat{f}(x)-f(x)\}^2$. I know $\hat{f}(x)$ is `y` from `est` but I have to compute all $ISE$. Is there any way to compute this on R or any package? I have to test this for multiple kernels. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you designed $f$ on spec and therefore know what is exactly, you can just integrate $(\hat{f}(x)-f(x))^2$ numerically using quadrature. Your values of the limits and $dx$ should agree with your set values in the density() call, or with the default values. Either way, the values can be extracted from your density() object, which you call *est*.

I think you will find that the various kernels perform very similarly. For details on KDE, the best reference is Bruce Hansen's  [unfinished opus](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf). 17 years and counting! Most recent change was last month! (Go, Bruce, go!) See chapter 17, in particular 17.9 on kernel selection. 
https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf

N.B. Because density estimates have bias, and because bias is proportional to the curvature of $f$ ( $f"$, the second derivative) you *should* calculate the KDE of the derivatives in order to make a bias-corrected estimate. And also note that the bias=0 at inflection points, so if there is something you can do *only* using inflection points, then that would be a computationally cheap/easy thing to do.

Comment: +1 for the reference to Bruce Hansen's book alone!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a previous answer, numerical integration is a solution in this case. 
Below you will find 2 ways of achieving this using R. 
The first solution uses an approximation of your kernel density estimates using spline interpolation. A second alternative is to use a trapezoid approximation (one easy to use function can be find in the R pkg sfsmisc).
The term $f(x)$ is computed for the "x"-values in the est object i.e. using *dnorm(est$x)*

Hope this helps.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(250) 
#Computing of bandwidth
h1 = bw.ucv(x1)
#Estimate
est = density(x1,kernel = "gaussian",bw = h1)

# Create approx func obj and integrate()
splxy = splinefun(est$x, (est$y - dnorm(est$x))^2)
integrate(splxy, lower = min(x1), upper = max(x1)) # res 0.0006681713

# Simple numerical integration in pkg sfsminsc
sfsmisc::integrate.xy(x = est$x, (est$y - dnorm(est$x))^2) # res 0.0006682952
```

Comment: Many thanks dear @Gi_F. it is what I was looking for. I am going to accept your answer. Just a small question if `x1` were from a exponential distribution, I should use `dexp` to compute `splxy` object, right?

Comment: I think that would work. On the other hand give a close look to the smoothed density obtained with the kde before computing the ISE. Boundaries could be an issue .